# backgroundImage is not working react, just the default white background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

So I am making a react app, and I think it's better to show you the code than explain:

Body.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import Clearsky from "Images/clearsky.jpg";
import Rain from "Images/clearsky.jpg";
import Cloudy from "Images/clearsky.jpg";

const type = {
    CLEARSKY: "clearsky",
    RAIN: "rain",
    CLOUDY: "cloudy"
}

class LeftSide extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            type: this.props.type,
            degrees: this.props.degrees
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ""
        );
    }
}

export default function Body() {
    //This is printing the correct path and if I type it in the browser I can see the image.
    console.log(type.CLEARSKY);

    const style = {
        //Not working
        backgroundImage: `url(${Clearsky})`
    }

    return (
        <div className="body" style={style}>
            <LeftSide />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Header.js (uses material-ui.com):

```
import React from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

import logo from "Images/icon.png";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
}));

export default function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="fixed" style={{ borderRadius: "25px"}}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                        Weather
                </Typography>

                    <img src={logo} alt="Icon" height="50" width="50" />
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import Body from "./Body.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Body />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

However the backgroundImage on Body.js is not working, just the default white background.

Tried:
Image from an online server (not a local image).
Setting backgroundSize.

EDIT:
My directory:
[image]
src:
[image]
Images:

[image]

EDIT 2:
I have noticed that if I change the LeftSide component to return

```
<p>A</p>
```

Instead of "" it will render this in the browser:
[image]

Part of the image has been rendered.
Now I believe it is something with the css.

Comment: Did the remote image work? Also are you sure the path to the Images directory is correct from the context of your `LeftSide` component?

Comment: @segFault No the remote image did not work. What do you mean the path to the image directory from the context of the LeftSide component? If you mean the imports from the top of Body.js, then yes it is, I'll update the question.

Comment: change backgroundImage: `url(${Clearsky})` to backgroundImage: `url(${type.CLEARSKY})` and CLEARSKY: "clearsky"  to CLEARSKY: "Images/clearsky.jpg" it will reference the path to the Image.

Comment: @DcoderZ Still the same. Also tried with require instead of just the path; CLEARSKY: require("Images/clearsky.jpg")

Comment: Can you post a picture of your directory?

Comment: @DcoderZ See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by adding the following css:

```
    const style = {
        //Now working
        backgroundImage: `url(${Clearsky})`,
        height: "100vh",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
    }
```

The issue was the height and the size.

Comment: Just to check if my reasoning below was right: do you confirm your problem was just the div dimensions as I pointed out below?

Comment: @saulotoledo Indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Do not forget to click the check in your response symbol to also mark your question as answered. :)

Comment: @saulotoledo Haha sure, but I need to wait 2 days for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code is correct, but the div with the background has no `width` and `height` enough to be visible. Please check if this is the case.

Working sample (see lines 31 and 32): https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-pine-wpdw7